# WordPress on two separate servers, first one with nginx, second one with php-fpm. Where to keep static files?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

For example, I have two servers (or VMs). On the first one I have Nginx installed, on the second one - PHP-FPM. And I need to deploy some app, like WordPress, which does not have two separate folders for scripts and static files, and sometimes scripts can write into static files. How to do this? As far as I understand, I should keep scripts on backend server, but what should I do with static files? I should keep all the files (scripts+static) on the both servers, and sync them? Then how can I sync them?
Or I should keep scripts only on backend, and static only on frontend? But what will happen if some script want to access some static file, or write to it? Or should I set up second Nginx instance on backend server, and serve static files from backend nginx to frontend nginx, then cache them to disk on frontend?

I know, there should be more than one way to setup this, I just want to hear about how people usually do this and why.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that you'll get "good answers" to this question, thus I've flagged it as "primarily opinion-based." If you want to split `nginx` and `php-fpm` on two separate machines, and `Wordpress` isn't made for this, then yes, you've to find a way to make this work: Either put `nginx` and `php-fpm` on the same machine, or put all files on both. For the second choice, you could use [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/) or ... (multiple other tools).

Comment: "Or should I set up second Nginx instance on backend server, and serve static files from backend nginx to frontend nginx, then cache them to disk on frontend?" What's the role then of the frontend `nginx`? Is the frontend `nginx` then of any use?

Comment: How many visits got the site per day?

Comment: This setup would need centralized storage as gf mentioned. Is there a specifi reason you want to separate the NGINX and FPM servers? How many server are you talking about?